# ld is unable to find file

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, g++

I working on a RedHat system.

```
uname -m 
x86_64
```

All the libs are of 32 bit.

```
/usr/bin/ld lib/libssh2.so
lib/libssh2.so could not read symbols: File in wrong format

file lib/libssh2.so
lib/libssh2.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

While compiling I am getting error:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Command to compile:

```
g++ src/Testcase.o src/Test.o -L../testcase/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib \
    -lcrypto -lz -lpthread -lssl -lcurl -lssh2 -o ./debug/testcase
```

Comment: You need to install the 64-bit version of the SSH2 library, or specify the location where the 64-bit version of it is installed, or rebuild the software as 32-bit code (use `g++ -m32` and/or `gcc -m32`).

Comment: I am building the sw in 32 bit code. 

/usr/bin/ld lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1
lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

file lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1
lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Comment: Are you sure?  What is the output of `file src/Test.o` and `file /usr/lib/libz.so` (for whatever path leads to the `-lz` library)?  On many (most?) x86_64 systems, the default compilation mode is 64-bit.  You should specify `-L ./lib` to find `lib/libssh2.so` (where the `./` is optional but explicit, and the space is also optional).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler .. Yes it generates 32bit libs. file <filename> output shows that the lib files are of 32 bit.

Comment: Does `file lib/libssh2.so` give exactly the same file type message as the other shared libraries?  Or is there a difference?  Did you build `lib/libssh2.so`, or did you collect a copy from somewhere else?  Does `ldd lib/libssh2.so` work without an error?  Are you planning to install `libssh2.so` into a system directory when you install your software — oh, don't worry about that right now, but it will become an issue to consider once you've got your code to link successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors.

The first one says that `libssh2.so` is a 32-bit shared library, but you link on a 64-bit platform. On a 64-bit platform it normally links to 64-bit objects by default. Add `-m32` switch to your compile and link command lines to build and link in 32-bit mode.

The second one is that the linker cannot find `-lssh2`. In this case you need to specify the directory where to look for `-lssh2`, e.g. `-L/usr/local/lib -lssh2`.

Comment: @Goku What exactly did you try?

Comment: @Goku Updated an answer for you.

Comment: All the libs are of 32-bits .
I changed the makefile added -m32 and compiled the code again.

Command used to compile:-
g++ -m32 src/Testcase.o src/Test1.o -L../testcase/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -lz -lpthread -lssl -lcurl -lssh2 ./debug/testcase

Comment: It searches in /usr/lib. Do I need to explicitly add -L/usr/lib -lssh2 ? 

usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libssh2.so when searching for -lssh2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh2